# Can I disable USB Debugging on Android smartpones from Windows via adb.exe?

Tags: adb, windows, debug

I have to install Applications on dozens of android smartphones and I am currently writing a program to automate this process. I know I can't remotely enable USB Debugging, so my question is: Can I use ADB.exe to send a command to the smartphone that disables USB Debugging immediatly or puts the disable in a command queue to execute at next reboot?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device in question is [root](/questions/tagged/root)ed, you can write to the system settings directly from a shell command in `adb shell`. The name of the setting to write depends on which Android version you have.

If your device **isn't** rooted, you can't change the USB debugging setting from `adb` or any non-system app.

Comment: It's not rooted. Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to switch usb debugging off through SQLite? Sadly I have little knowledge with Android.

Comment: No: that's the method that requires root.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible using ADB to disable USB debugging.

Using the appropriate shell input keyevent commands you can navigate the GUI and change the setting.

Comment: And what are those commands?