# How can I stop my Nexus 5X getting stuck in the loading screen?

Tags: boot, nexus-5x

My phone is stuck on the dots loading screen and won't load. It is rooted and it is a Nexus 5X. (No it is not the bootlooping issue). I cannot boot into recovery because the phone will not fully turn off as when I hold down the power button it just turns the screen off and back on and shows the device is corrupt screen, then goes onto the loading screens.

Do I have to wait for the battery to go down or is there another option. Thanks

Comment: Hold the power button for at least 12 seconds then load a fresh new ROM on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I disable USB Debugging on Android smartpones from Windows via adb.exe?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/can-i-disable-usb-debugging-on-android-smartpones-from-windows-via-adb-exe)

Comment: What's the relationship between title and content?

Answer (score 0):

To turn the device off, when it's in the bootloop phase, just hold down the VolDown key until the device restarts and takes you to fastboot. From there, you'll be able to choose the option to turn off.

Hope it's still a useful answer.